# Syntax error: Unexpected number at Object.parse, PHP to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I have built a contact form using AngularjS for my frontend and PHP for the mail client that sends the email. I want to pass data from PHP to Angular, telling Angular whether or not the email sent. However, when I try to do that, I get a "Syntax error: Unexpected number".

My PHP:

```
<?php
        require_once "../vendors/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

    print_r($_POST);
    $data = array();

    $sender_name = isset($_POST['sender_name']) ? $_POST['sender_name'] : '';
    $sender_email = isset($_POST['sender_email']) ? $_POST['sender_email'] : '';
    $sender_tel = isset($_POST['sender_tel']) ? $_POST['sender_tel'] : '';
    $sender_message = isset($_POST['sender_message']) ? $_POST['sender_message'] : '';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //Enable SMTP debugging. 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               
    //Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
    $mail->isSMTP();            
    //Set SMTP host name                          
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    //Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
    //Provide username and password     
    $mail->Username = "*****@gmail.com";                 
    $mail->Password = "******";                           
    //If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
    //Set TCP port to connect to 
    $mail->Port = 587;                                   

    $mail->From = $sender_email;
    $mail->FromName = $sender_name;


    $mail->addAddress("blah@blah.com", "Blah");

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "Message Sent from jcrageralternatives.com by: ".$sender_name;
    $mail->Body = "<p>Name: ".$sender_name."</p><p>Email Provided: ".$sender_email."</p><p>Phone Number Provided: ".$sender_tel."</p><p>Message: '".$sender_message."'</p>";
    $mail->AltBody = $sender_message;

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if(!$mail->send()) 
    {
        $data["success"] = false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $data["success"] = true;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

And my controller:

```
$http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : '/php/contact.php',
        data    : $.param($scope.contactData),  // pass in data as strings
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        }).then(function (response) {
             console.log(response.data);
        }
});
```

If I remove the `header('Content-Type: application/json');` from the PHP file and still `console.log(response.data)`, I get:

```
2016-01-16 02:34:28 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
    2016-01-16 02:34:28 Connection: opened
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP ry1sm18220246pab.30 - gsmtp
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [73.15.255.61]
                                      250-SIZE 35882577
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-CHUNKING
                                      250 SMTPUTF8
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [73.15.255.61]
                                      250-SIZE 35882577
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-CHUNKING
                                      250 SMTPUTF8
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: dmliaHUxMjAxQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Q0BycGVEMWVt
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Accepted
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<v@v>
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 OK ry1sm18220246pab.30 - gsmtp
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<****@gmail.com>
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 OK ry1sm18220246pab.30 - gsmtp
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354  Go ahead ry1sm18220246pab.30 - gsmtp
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Sat, 16 Jan 2016 02:34:28 +0000
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: **** **** <****@gmail.com>
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: v <v@v>
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Message Sent from jcrageralternatives.com by: v
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <421aa50e45d9e33b9b7c41918d99af59@localhost>
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:   boundary="b1_421aa50e45d9e33b9b7c41918d99af59"
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_421aa50e45d9e33b9b7c41918d99af59
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: as;lkdfjas;ldkf
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_421aa50e45d9e33b9b7c41918d99af59
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: <p>Name: v</p><p>Email Provided: v@v</p><p>Phone Number Provided: 1234567891</p><p>Message: 'as;lkdfjas;ldkf'</p>
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_421aa50e45d9e33b9b7c41918d99af59--
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-16 02:34:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
    2016-01-16 02:34:30 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 OK 1452911670 ry1sm18220246pab.30 - gsmtp
    2016-01-16 02:34:30 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
    2016-01-16 02:34:30 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection ry1sm18220246pab.30 - gsmtp
    2016-01-16 02:34:30 Connection: closed
    {"success":true}
```

The first location of the Unexpected Number error, after Objects.parse (native) is at fromJSON from the AngularJS library. Where is the unexpected number and what can I do to fix this so I can read `response.data["success"]` ?

Comment: Disable SMTP-Debugging so it doesn't print out all that stuff, maybe?!

Comment: @tkausl legitimately feel so dumb right now lol, thank you!